# Jboss-as7 can't find oracle driver despite it being deployed

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I'm using hibernate to connect to a database from a web application in jboss-as7. This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HBOService">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="hboweb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****"/>
</properties>
```

I also deployed ojdb6.jar in my jboss server, as a matter of fact I can see it's listed in the Manage Deployements tab of the admin console.

Still I get this message when trying to start the application:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: HBOService] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver class not found
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:104)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @778f9ba9 (roots: C:\Users\Developer1\Desktop\Development\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:101)
... 23 more
```

Is oracle.jdb.driver actually in the classpath? How can I know?

Comment: I recently use jboss too. You've done the job on the webapp side. There're still things you need to check on the container side (JBoss). In order to make this work : You need to install the JDBC Driver and define the DataSource itself. For my own case, I've defined these inside the standalone.xml file. Please check [Data Source Configuration in AS 7](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7)

Comment: I did install the jdbc driver as a deployment. As for the datasource, do I still need a container datasource? I thought the application would just use the parameters in persistence.xml.

Comment: In my case, I still need a container DS. I've configured the params of connection in JBoss as described in [Defining the DataSource itself](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7#jive_content_id_Defining_the_DataSource_itself) and only keep a minimum of params in persistence.xml to find out this DS. It might have other way to do it. But I'll let the experts to answer you ^^

Answer (score 0):

With Jboss-server the jdbc driver will be loaded from its module class loader, in your case it will scan and load class from the path
**C:\Users\Developer1\Desktop\Development\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules**
Becaused oracle.jdb.driver is included in the jar file jdbc-oracle.jar or ojdbc6.jar so you can try to do a file search inside above module folder. If you can not find the file, you can add new module to your server according to below guide
1)Downloaded ojdbc6-11.jar and placed it inside the folder 
`$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main`

2)Created the file module.xml under $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main and this is the content of the file

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

3) Add a dependency on the com.oracle.ojdbc6 module using a MANIFEST.MF file in the WEB-INF lib dir with contents:
Dependencies: com.oracle.ojdbc6

This can be created using the following Maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
         <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
               <Dependencies>com.oracle.ojdbc6
</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
         </archive>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I added the ojdbc6.jar to C:\Users\Developer1\Desktop\Development\Servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments. Wouldn't that be enough? Why use modules?

Comment: Jboss AS class loader is not read from standalone\‌​deployments so of course what you did would not work. I will updated my answer to be more detail on the configuraiton

Comment: I tried that except I created the folder as $JBOSS_HOME/modules/oracle/jdbc/main and the name attribute was oracle.jdbc

Comment: No, and I also opened the jar file and the class is there

Comment: Yes. What about the 2nd and 3rd step in this url? Do I have to do that? http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7